# Load multidimensional JSON array of objects into selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, selectize.js

I want to load this JSON into selectize:

```
{"platforms":

[{"id":32,"name":"Sega Saturn","slug":"saturn"},

{"id":14,"name":"Mac","slug":"mac"},

{"id":47,"name":"Virtual Console (Nintendo)","slug":"vc"},

{"id":34,"name":"Android","slug":"android"},

{"id":84,"name":"SG-1000","slug":"sg1000"},

{"id":58,"name":"Super Famicom","slug":"sfam"},

{"id":82,"name":"Web browser","slug":"browser"}]

}
```

I would like it to operate very similar to [this example provided by the Selectize.js developers](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/api.html) (excluding the URL portion in each), except obviously instead of the pre-made ID's and names using my json data.

Any help is appreciated.

Code I'm currently trying to use:

```
options: [
    for (var i = 0; i < platforms.platforms.length; i++) 
    {
        var counter = platforms.platforms[i];
        {id: counter.id, title: counter.name},
        console.log(counter.name);
    }
```

Here's what the JSON looks like when logging it in the console:

[image][image]

**EDIT:** [This is another example that I'm looking at as it uses JSON.](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/movies.html)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing that specific JSON into the selectize select box. I would like to base it off of that example.

Comment: What do you mean? What "trouble" do you have? What have you tried to use? What is the error message? What's wrong in the image? It looks as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `for` inside an array/object, when you declare a variable. Javascript is not a template like PHP&HTML.

You also missed the `.slug`. Try this:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"platforms":[{"id":32,"name":"Sega Saturn","slug":"saturn"},{"id":14,"name":"Mac","slug":"mac"},{"id":47,"name":"Virtual Console (Nintendo)","slug":"vc"},{"id":34,"name":"Android","slug":"android"},{"id":84,"name":"SG-1000","slug":"sg1000"},{"id":58,"name":"Super Famicom","slug":"sfam"},{"id":82,"name":"Web browser","slug":"browser"}]}');
var options = [];
$.each(data.platforms, function()
{
    options.push({
        id: this.id,
        title: this.name,
        url: "hhtp://site.com/"+this.slug
    });
});
var $select = $('#select-tools').selectize({
    maxItems: null,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    options: options,
    create: false
});
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, but the code is fine. (No errors output) Selectize.js just doesn't like that code for some reason. None of it's custom CSS or JS loads, and the page just has an empty selection box.

Comment: I updated my post with another example, also, I purposely left out the ".slug", as I didn't wish to do anything with it. How could I just make it do nothing with that?

Comment: I don't know what the 2nd example should do, what what you want it to do. If you have a question that is a real question, ask it, but we can't figure out what you'd like to see, and won't do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show has several syntax errors. You are not very familiar with JavaScript, are you?

@klenium is right, both in his suggestion, and by showing a full code that can run on its own. You should go to a site like Plunkr or JSFiddle, add the right imports, run this code there, and if it doesn't do what you expect, put here the link to the page, so we can check what was wrong.

Note: one interest of Selectize is that it can get nearly any data without preprocessing, so the code can probably (untested!) be reduced to:

```
var $select = $('#select-tools').selectize({
    maxItems: null,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    options: data.platforms, // Just use the Json data as it is
    create: false
});
```

Comment: You are correct, I'm trying to learn Javascript as I go. As I feel I learn better that way. I appreciate the tip, and after review klenium's code did in fact work it was just my HTML that was causing the issues. Thanks.